# Category with class active or not in PHP

Tags: php

I have this.

```
<?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'portfolio?cat=$cat_name')){ ?>
        <li class="active" role="category"><a href="portfolio.php?cat=<?php echo $cat_name; ?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></a></li>
<?php } else { ?>
        <li role="category"><a href="portfolio.php?cat=<?php echo $cat_name; ?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
```

I just want to make the typical active category but getting the parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: 'portfolio?cat=$cat_name' will output that literal string. Use double quotes if you want to use the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Bert's comment about the single quotes, it will be the literal `cat_name` with a `$` in front, not the value of `$cat_name` as you probably assume.

Also, why don't you just use:

```
if($_REQUEST['cat'] == $cat_name) { // ...
```

I mean, it already is a query param that ends up in `$_REQUEST` (unless you have weird server configuration, then it probably should be `$_GET`).

Also you don't distinguish between the two likely return values of `stripos` which are in your case `0` and `false` (the one meaning, the needle starts at position 0 of the haystack, and the other, that the needle wasn't found). So at the very least, you would have to `stripos(...) !== false`

Comment: Exactly! Thanks dude :)

I used get but whatever!

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes here change `'` to `"`

```
<?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "portfolio?cat=$cat_name")){ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($_GET['cat'] == $cat_name){ ?>
        <li class="active" role="category"><a href="portfolio.php?cat=<?php echo $cat_name; ?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <li role="category"><a href="portfolio.php?cat=<?php echo $cat_name; ?>"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
```